# JS Lenght function fails when i put Quotation marks on the text area, MVC 4 Razor View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, i made a simple Form where you write whatever you want on the textarea, ou click submit and then it prints the string and also gives you the lenght of it, it works fine until i put quotation marks on the text area, it gives me the wrong number of characters.

here is my Controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modifique esta plantilla para poner en marcha su aplicación ASP.NET MVC.";

            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string text)
        {

            Session["Text"] = text;
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {


           ViewBag.Message = Session["Text"];

            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

My Form View.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Página principal";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Página principal";
}

<h3>Formulario</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
    @Html.Label("Escribe lo que quieras")<br />
    @Html.TextArea("text")<br />

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>


}
```

And the result view.

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Exito";
}



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hola, Escribiste: ";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<script type="text/javascript">


    var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: "+'@(ViewBag.Message)';
       var myLength = Texto.length;


       document.write("La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de "+myLength+" (Incluyendo el 'hola, escribiste')");


       </script>
```

why does it fail with quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to this line:

```
var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: "+'@(ViewBag.Message)';
```

You need the quotation marks around `@(ViewBag.Message)` because this line is evaluated by two totally different languages. You need to understand the difference between what is happening on the server and what is happening on the client. Here is what happens:

1. The SERVER prepares the content to send to the client. In doing so, among other things, it parses all Razor expressions on the page and, where appropriate, replaces them with content. In this case the expression @(ViewBag.Message) is replaced with whatever the user entered. The quotation marks are outside of the Razor expression, so they will be left alone. So for example this line could be sent as `var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: "+'uno dos tres';`
2. The page with the replaced content is sent to the client
3. The CLIENT recognizes that the code is Javascript and executes it. At this point the content has already been replaced, so Javascript doesn't actually see the part `@(ViewBag.Message)`, and it has no idea it was ever there. All it sees is the replaced line as per point 1

Now try to think about what would happen if the single quotes weren't there. In that case the Javascript would see the following line:

```
var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: "+uno dos tres;
```

Which is clearly wrong because there are no quotation marks around some of the text. This is why you need the quotation marks.

Also, you need to careful in this case, because if your user enters a text that contains a single quote, your code will break. For example if the text to display is `Don't enter single quotes`, the "replaced" line would become:

```
var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: "+'Don't enter single quotes';
```

The above line has mismatched quotes and throws an exception, as well as leaving your application vuylnerable to a kind of attack called XSS (Cross-Site Scripting).

So if you just need to display the lenght of the text, there is a better way to do this. You don't need Javascript to count the characters, you can do it directly in Razor. Just get rid of the last script tag and use the following code directly in your HTML (not inside a script):

```
@{
    var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: " + ViewBag.Message;
}

<p>La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de @Texto.Lenght (Incluyendo el 'hola, escribiste')</p>
```

EDIT: If you really must use Javascript to count the characters, you could do it like this:

```
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <h2 id="userMessage">@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: " + document.getElementById('userMessage').innerHTML;
    var myLength = Texto.length;
    document.write("La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de "+myLength+" (Incluyendo el 'hola, escribiste')");
</script>
```

And here is the jQuery version:

```
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    <h2 id="userMessage">@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var Texto = "Hola, Escribiste: " + $('#userMessage').html();
    var myLength = Texto.length;
    document.write("La cantidad de caracteres en la oracion es de "+myLength+" (Incluyendo el 'hola, escribiste')");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, the thinks is that i was requested to use JS to show the lenght of the string, actually jquery but i wasnt able tu do it with jq.

Comment: I edited my post to add some code at the end to do it with Javascript (or jQuery) in a more secure way.

Comment: ok, this really help me, it works, thank you very much my friend, can you explain me where do you validate the espaped chars(""''}+) and those?

Comment: oh, now i get it, so in simple words you "converted" the viewbag to an html enviroment?

Comment: Yes, I simply changed the approach and instead of printing the content from Razor directly into a JS variable, I am using the content that was already printed on the page in the `h2` tag (I just added an ID to better identify it) and counting that value. This totally solves the problem of the single quotes because the `Texto` variable now takes the value from the DOM.